# Using a power line filter and earth

Tags: ac, filter

We are planning to use [this](https://www.schaffner.com/product-storage/datasheets/fn-2090/) power-line-filter to reduce the possible power line noise in our data acquisition system. And the data-sheet as pdf can be downloaded from [here](https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-tYWEj-TXAhWGZlAKHekyDocQFgi2ATAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.schaffner.com%2Fproduct%2Fdatasheet%2Ffn-2090-multi-stage-emcemi-filter-with-excellent-attenuation-performance%2F&usg=AOvVaw0MwFDs2EzDgZrBUb5xrEWn).

The data sheet shows the wiring diagram of the filter as follows:

[image]

But I was planning to use this filter for PC and many transducers ect. by also maintaining the safety.

So for my question I have drawn the following:

[image]

As you see above if I use this filter between the power outlet and the power strip as in 2nd figure, the earth connection(yellow-green wire) no more exists after the filter. I have equipment which is chassis grounded to earth for safety.

Wouldn't it be risky to use this filter since earth wire cannot be used anymore for safety? Does anybody have experience with such application and filters?

Answer (score 2):

Just because there's only one earth tag doesn't mean you can't connect two wires to it, one for the goes-in, one for the goes-out.

However, wiring that into a power strip is not a good thing to do. Get a filtered power strip.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to ask if removing earth is a good idea, then it isn't. Only do it when you absolutely know what you are doing Just use  proper filter instead.

These filters are building blocks of bigger devices where they feed into a psu that works with floating in and outputs. They are not meant to be attached to a power strip.

If you need a power strip with filter, buy a power strip with filter.